# Exceptional points for generalized north-eastern knight walks in a quarter plane

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, chess

Given two coprime integers $a < b$ of different parities, only a finite number of
points in $\mathbb N^2$ cannot be reached by a walk in $\mathbb N^2$, starting at the origin
and using only steps of the form $(b,\pm a),(\pm a,b)$ (and thus making an acute angle
with the north-eastern vector $(1,1)$).

Is there a good upper bound on the number of such exceptional points? Is there a good
upper bound on the coordinate sum $x+y$ of such an exceptional point $(x,y)$?

(Remark: A naive proof that almost all points can be reached gives an upper bound which is probably very far from the true value.)

Added in order to comply with the request made by user 9072:

**Proof that almost all points can be reached:** We consider $v=a(b,a)+b(-a,b)=(0,a^2+b^2)$ and $w=(a,b)+(-a,b)=(0,2b)$.

Since $a,b$ are coprime and have different parities, $a^2+b^2$ and $2b$ are coprime. The set
$$\{k(a^2+b^2),k=0,\ldots,2b-1\}$$
with largest element $(2b-1)(a^2+b^2)<4b^3$ contains thus representants of all classes of $\mathbb Z/(2b)\mathbb Z$. This shows that all elements $(0,y)$ with $y\geq 4b^3$ are of the form $\mathbb N v+\mathbb N w$. Using the obvious symmetry with respect to coordinates, the same holds for $(x,0)$ with $x\geq  4b^3$. We get thus everything
in $4b^3(1,1)+\mathbb N^2$. All non-reachable points are thus contained in the two strips of width $4b^3-1$
parallel to coordinate axes.  Let  $(x,y)$
with $x=\min(x,y)<4b^3$ be a point of the vertical strip. If
$y\geq \left\lceil\frac{4b^3}{a}\right\rceil b+4b^3$, then
$$(x,y)\in \mathbb N(-a,b)+(4b^3)(1,1)+\mathbb N^2$$ and we are done.

This gives the very crude upper bound $64b^7$ on the number of non-reachable points in $\mathbb N^2$.

Some computational data:

For $a=1$ and $b\in\{2,4,6,\ldots,16\}$ the number of missing elements is given by $$\frac{1}{12}(4b^5-3b^4+8b^3)$$
and the largest coordinate occuring in missing points is given by $b^3-b$.

For $a=2$ and $b\in\{3,5,7,9,\ldots,17\}$ the number of missing elements is given by $$\frac{1}{12}(2b^5+3b^4-2b^3-24b^2+12b+9)$$
and the largest coordinate occuring in missing points is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}(b^3+2b^2-9b)$$
if $b>3$ and by $10$ for $b=3$ (the polynomial formula yields the wrong value $9$).

For $a=3$ and $b\in\{4,8,10,14,16,20,22,26\}$ the number of missing elements is given by
$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{36}(4b^5+15b^4-8b^3-240b^2+160b+384)\qquad&b\equiv 1\pmod 3,\\
               \frac{1}{36}(4b^5+15b^4-8b^3-240b^2+184b+360)&b\equiv 2\pmod 3\end{cases}$$
and the largest coordinate occuring in missing points is given by
$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{3}(b^3+4b^2-17b)\qquad&b\equiv 1\pmod 3,\\
                \frac{1}{3}(b^3+4b^2-15b)&b\equiv 2\pmod 3.\end{cases}$$

For $a=4$ and $b\in\{5,7,9,\ldots,21\}$ the number of missing elements is given by
$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{12}(b^5+6b^4-b^3-162b^2+120b+540)\qquad&b\equiv 1\pmod 4,\\
               \frac{1}{12}(b^5+6b^4-b^3-162b^2+132b+528)&b\equiv 3\pmod 4\end{cases}$$
and the largest coordinate occuring in missing points is given by
$$\frac{1}{4}(b^3+6b^2-27b).$$

There seems to be some structure in these data: Fixing $a$, in all examples the number of missing elements seems to be of the form
$$\frac{1}{3a}b^5+\frac{3a-4}{4a}b^4+O(b^3)$$
and the largest coordinate occuring in missing elements seems to be of the form
$$\frac{1}{a}b^3+\frac{2(a-1)}{a}b^2+O(b)\ .$$

Comment: Using the theory developed by the Frobenius problem (postage stamp problem) and considering how far the points are from the line x=-y, I expect a bound of O((a+b)^2).  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.02.22

Comment: A bound of the form $O((a+b)^2)$ (for the number of points) is far too optimistic, I believe. 

Comment: I was thinking of distance from the origin.  For number of points, replace the exponent 2 by 4 for my expectations.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.22

Comment: Do you know the answers for any particular examples? Say, $a=1$, $b=2$?

Comment: Could you perhaps include the naive bound.  

Comment: For (1,2) I get 6 points in the quadrant that are not covered, wwith (2,2)I and (3,0) among the extremes.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.02.22

Answer (score 11):

I would like to see  a solution. Below are a few comments which were obvious once I thought of them. I guess  they do allow a naive argument that the number  of exceptional points is finite, but I wonder if the OP has a nicer one.

I'll start with the (to me)

**non-obvious observation**: It appears that the exceptional points are all nicely contained in a non-convex quadrilateral with two sides on the axes (of course) and the other two lines of slopes $-b/a$ and $-a/b$. For example $a=4,b=7$ gives 2032 exceptional points. We can reach  all points $(0,z)$ and $(z,0).$ for $z \ge 110$ as well as for for $42$ smaller values of $z$

0, 14, 28, 41, 42, 47, 49, 55, 56, 57, 61, 63, 65, 69, 70, 71, 74, 75, 77, 79, 80, 82, 83, 84, 85, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108

Hence there are 68 exceptional points on each axis.

The points $(3+4j,112-7j)$ and $(112-7j,3+4j)$ for $0 \le j \le 16$ are also exceptional and they lie on two lines which cross between $(43,44)$ and $(44,43)$. Here are the $\mathbf{2032}$ exceptional points:

[image: exceptional points]

**more obvious observations**

Recall that given positive co-prime integers $u \lt v$, the set $S=\{su+tv \mid s,t \ge 0\}$ contains exactly one member of each pair $\{m,uv-u-v+m\}$ so  neither $uv-2u-v$ nor $uv-u-v$ is in $S$ but everything between them or larger is (because $0$ and $u$ are in $S$ but anything between them or smaller is not).

- Let the *rank* of point $(x,y)$ be $x+y$ so that there are $r+1$ points of rank $r$ in $\mathbb N^2.$  Then each move increases the rank by either $b+a$ or $b-a$. Hence half the ranks up to $(b+a)(b-a)-(b+a)-(b-a)=b^2-2b+a^2$ are completely empty. This allows some lower bound. Those comments stay true even if we are allowed to venture outside $\mathbb N^2$ and then come back in. So it might be worthwhile bounding the number of exceptional points in $\mathbb N^2$ under those relaxed rules (which allow us to reach the otherwise exceptional points such as  $(b-a,b-a)$ ).
- Under the strict rules we may assume that we reach the non-exceptional points by first using only the two vectors $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ followed by later use of only $(-a,b)$ and $(b,-a).$
- Using just the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ gives only points which both have a rank $k(a+b)$ and are inside the cone $C$ between the lines  $ax=by$ and $bx=ay.$  The first time that the entire rank is filled (using only those two vectors) is for $k_0=s+t$ obtained from the unique positive solution to $sa+tv=(a-1)(b-1)$. So $k_0 \le b-1-\frac {b-1}a.$
- Once we have a full rank between $(ka,kb)$ to $(kb,ka)$ for each $k \ge k_0$ (if not sooner) we can shift using the other two vectors to get full ranks from $(ka+jb,kb-ja)$ to $(kb-ja,ka+jb)$ (choosing ($1 \le j \le kb/a$). With a bit of work we could describe an $r_0$ so that we are sure to have every rank for $r \ge r_0$ full from $(r,0)$ to $(0,r).$

Comment: Beautiful patterns in that plot of the nonexceptional points!

Comment: thanks. That plot is actually the exceptional points. If one starts from any exceptional point and goes backwards in $\mathbb N^2$ using $(\pm a,-b)$ and $(-b, \pm a)$ then one only sees exceptional points. I wonder what the minimal exceptional starting set is. There might be some nice duality as with the set $S$ in $\mathbb N$